# NTP Time calculating

Tags: time, c++, pic-ccs

I have this code and i use in my device.

```
PIC18F252 PCH compiler CCS 5.007
//t_time_stamp=3776590560;            // 2019/09/04  12:56:00
utc_sec = t_time_stamp % 60;          //int32

min_temp = t_time_stamp / 60;         //float32 
min_temp_int = t_time_stamp / 60;     //int32
utc_min = min_temp_int % 60;          //int32

hour_temp = min_temp / 60;            //float32 
hour_temp_int = min_temp / 60;        //int32
utc_hour = hour_temp_int % 24;        //int32

day_temp1 = hour_temp / 24;           //float32 
day_temp1_int = hour_temp / 24;       //int32
day_temp2_int = day_temp1_int % 1461; //int32
utc_day_cnt = (day_temp2_int % 365) + 1; 

utc_year_cnt = day_temp1 / 365.25;    //int32 code here
```

It work correctly until 5 last month,
but `hour_temp_int` is not correctly now; `hour_temp_int` is 11 at 10:26 to 10:30 but it should be 10!
**Only this parameter and at this time is not correct!**
What is my mistake?
[image: Basic and Special types]
I change types float32 to unsigned float32  or float48 but i have Error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for [Justme](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/199993/justme)
I change start time from 1900 to 2000 and use 32 bit variable by this way my problem was solved! in this case we don't have more than 31 bit data and it work to 2036!
this is my new code

```
t_time_stamp= t_time_stamp - 3155760000;
utc_sec = t_time_stamp % 60;
min_temp_int = (unsigned int32) (t_time_stamp / 60);
utc_min = min_temp_int % 60;
hour_temp_int = (unsigned int32) ( min_temp_int / 60);
utc_hour = hour_temp_int % 24;
day_temp1_int = (unsigned int32) (hour_temp_int / 24);
day_temp2_int = day_temp1_int % 1461;
utc_day_cnt = (day_temp2_int % 365) + 1;
utc_year_cnt = (unsigned int32) (day_temp1_int / 365.25);
```

Answer (score 2):

Mistake is to use floating point numbers here as precision of 1 is needed. With floating point numbers there will be rounding errors and for example 32-bit floats do not have precision of 1 any more at values larger than 16777215.

I don't have the same rounding problem on my PC, but a different one:

> 3776579879 -> 9:57:59
>
> 3776579880 -> 10:58:0
>
> 3776579999 -> 10:59:59
>
> 3776580000 -> 10:0:0

Comment: i use code in my products at 10 years ago so and this code at all time is ok and only at  last 5 month 10:26:00 to 10:30:00 is not correct and only at hour ! why second , min , day, and other is correct?

Comment: Seconds are correct because calculations uses integer modulo arithmetic. Minutes are correct because calculations use integer division and integer modulo arithmetic. Hours may have rounding errors because it is using float arithmetic, first integer seconds are converted to float minutes with a float division, and then to float hours with float division before storing the result back into integer hours variable. I did not analyze if your day calculation is correct or not.

Comment: I chang to float64 but it make Error 48 and  for unsigned float32 it make Error 38

Comment: Your answer is make sense  And "why the answer was correct" is a good question.
I have to  decrease 100 years so that the computation is less than 32 bits